# What is the C++ equivalent code of this Python slicing statement?

Tags: c++, code-translation

I am trying to translate the following Python statements to C++:

```python
some_array = [11, 22, 33, 44]
first, rest = some_array[0], some_array[1:]
```

What I have so far is this:

```
int array[4] = {11, 22, 33, 44};
vector<int> some_array (array, 4);
int first = some_array.front();
vector<int> rest = some_array;
rest.erase(rest.begin());
```

- How can this be shorter and/or efficiently rewritten?
- Can this be written without using C++ templates and/or vectors?
- Is there an online service (or software) for translating such non-trivial Python code snippets to human readable C++ code?

Comment: This is not a python question. Please describe your request in english.

Comment: There is `splice` for lists

Comment: Start by reading a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) reference.

Comment: do you care for performance, readability or convenience?

Comment: First performance, next readability.

Comment: @lifebalance that's the wrong way around.

Comment: In this case, my priorities are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
vector<int> rest = some_array;
rest.erase(rest.begin());
```

can be shortened to:

```
vector<int> rest(some_array.begin() + 1, some_array.end());
```

If you can use C++11, you can shorten the whole code to:

```
vector<int> some_array { 11, 22, 33, 44 };
int first = some_array.front();
vector<int> rest (some_array.begin() + 1, some_array.end());
```

Although I doubt this would be much of an advantage...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> arr = {11, 22, 33, 44};
    int first = arr[0];
    vector<int> rest;

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        rest.push_back(arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or you can do this in this way also,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> arr = {11, 22, 33, 44};
    int first = arr[0];
    vector<int> rest(arr.begin() + 1, arr.end());

    return 0;
}
```